# Minecraft Modding 1.7.10 cant set up texture to item

Tags: java, minecraft

I hope someone can help.

Can`t set up texture, i tried many times and every time i get purple-black texture. (Sorry for my english)

Code (Main Class):

```
package com.ilshk.justamod;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;

@Mod(modid = "JustAMod", name = "Just A Mod", version = "0.1")
public class JustAMod {

    public static Item itemWeirdDust;

    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        // ITEM AND BLOCK REGEIEIEIESTERING
        itemWeirdDust = new itemWeirdDust().setUnlocalizedName("dustweird").setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabMaterials).setTextureName("JustAMod:dustweird");
        GameRegistry.registerItem(itemWeirdDust, itemWeirdDust.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));

    }
    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        // Proxy, Tile Entity, GUI, Packet Registering
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Code (Item Class);

```
package com.ilshk.justamod;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;

public class itemWeirdDust extends Item {
}
```

Texture Path: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G1Uq.png)

Comment: `setTextureName` is deprecated. Use `ItemModelMesher.register()` instead.  Read this for more info: https://bedrockminer.jimdo.com/modding-tutorials/basic-modding-1-8/first-item/

Comment: @Campbell it was completely removed in 1.8 but the still the way to go in 1.7 which is the version asked about

Comment: Can you post the texture that you are trying to use?

Comment: Rename to `justamod` in all lower case. This is good practice prior to 1.11 (due to the way different operating systems handle casing: some are case sensitive--such as the jar file--and some are not) and enforced (will throw errors) in 1.11.  Also insure that your folder is not named `JustAMod.textures.items` and is actually a nested folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your texture name has to match the name that you put for the image in your source folder that you have for the textures.

This is how mine is setup and it works for me.

`YourItemName = new Item().setUnlocalizedName("YourItemName").setTextureName("YourFolderName:YourExactTextureName").setCreativeTab(YourCreativeTabYouWantitoGoIn);`